# MTPuTTY Alt+Tab weird behavior

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, keyboard-shortcuts, putty

I've been having an annoying issue with MTPuTTY on Windows 8.1 where when alt+tabbing out of the application, the first tap of alt+tab results in focus on MTPuTTY and not the next application like the shortcut usually behaves. This seems to only occur when a session is active.

Answer (score 5):

This appears to be a known issue: https://github.com/jimradford/superputty/issues/216

It doesn't sound like their hopeful about fixing it soon unfortunately.

The last comment in the link suggests using autohotkeys to basically trigger two alt-tab commands instead of one when trying to tab and mtputty is open, which is a good solution if you regularly use autohotkey or don't mind adding it to your autostartup.

Yeah I know you asked this awhile ago and probably don't care any more, but any time I find an unanswered stack overflow question I wanted an answer for I try to go back and answer it after I figure out the solution to my problem.

Comment: Here you go... There is one more hit on your answer

Comment: @MadhusoodanP lol, thank you.  I apparently got a silver medal for your upvote heh.

Comment: @dsollen You are doing it right. The whole idea of stackexchange is to make questions and answers work not only for one person that asked, but for many people who will want an answer to the same question in the future. So, it doesn't matter if topic-starter is still interested in the answer or not. There are always other people who will find this question through a search engine and will thank you for the answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a way to fix this issue in [WinSSHTerm](https://github.com/WinSSHTerm/WinSSHTerm/releases/tag/2.21.0), which is another PuTTY wrapper. So it should be possible to be fixed in PuTTY wrappers like MTPuTTY or SuperPuTTY too.